# Converting a column of MULTIPOLYGON data to lat and long in python

Tags: python

My dataset includes a column of MULTIPOLYGON like below. I am searching a lot to extract the lat and long of data, but I am not able to do that. can anyone help me please?

```
    name                wkt
0   place_1 McDonald's  POLYGON ((13.4611920000000005 52.4709870000000009, 13.4610299999999992 52.4706600000000023, 13.4611959999999993 52.4706290000000024, 13.4612090000000002 52.4706550000000007, 13.4613589999999999 52.4709560000000010, 13.4611920000000005 52.4709870000000009))
1   place_2 McDonald's  POLYGON ((13.4683480000000007 52.5471599999999981, 13.4684080000000002 52.5471560000000011, 13.4684589999999993 52.5471360000000018, 13.4684910000000002 52.5471050000000020, 13.4684960000000000 52.5470729999999975, 13.4685500000000005 52.5470740000000021, 13.4685430000000004 52.5470449999999971, 13.4685269999999999 52.5470180000000013, 13.4684939999999997 52.5469920000000030, 13.4684449999999991 52.5469719999999967, 13.4684080000000002 52.5469629999999981, 13.4683630000000001 52.5469599999999986, 13.4683650000000004 52.5469960000000000, 13.4683159999999997 52.5469989999999996, 13.4682650000000006 52.5470189999999988, 13.4682329999999997 52.5470510000000033, 13.4682270000000006 52.5470880000000022, 13.4682469999999999 52.5471220000000017, 13.4682899999999997 52.5471480000000000, 13.4683480000000007 52.5471599999999981))
```

the desired out put will be like this :

```
    name                long.                       lat.   
0   place_1 McDonald's  13.4611920000000005.       52.4709870000000009
...
```

Comment: What is the desired output for this case?

Comment: I just want 2 column named Lat and Long .. I want to extract lat and long from this

Comment: can you help me please?

Comment: You're descibing the desired output, it'll be helpful if we can see the actual numbers. Please [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/66710758/edit) your question.

Comment: thanks, I updated the question ..

Comment: So the first two numbers are the long. and lat. and everything else is ignored?

Comment: Yes exactly, I would be really grateful if you can help me.. I put so much time, I couldn't solve it..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can use [`itertools.takewhile`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.takewhile) in this case:

```py
def get_long_lat(s):
    it = iter(s[10:])  # Get the iterable of the string, not including the first 10 characters.
    long = ''.join(takewhile(lambda c: c.isnumeric() or c == '.', it))  # Take from the iterable as lomg as it's a part of a number. This we also take the next character after the number but won't include it in the output.
    lat = ''.join(takewhile(lambda c: c.isnumeric() or c == '.', it))  # Do it again.
    return long, lat
```

Use case:

```py
>>> get_long_lat('POLYGON ((13.4611920000000005 52.4709870000000009, 13.4610299999999992 52.4706600000000023, 13.4611959999999993 52.4706290000000024, 13.4612090000000002 52.4706550000000007, 13.4613589999999999 52.4709560000000010, 13.4611920000000005 52.4709870000000009))')
('13.4611920000000005', '52.4709870000000009')  # Note that those are strings, not floats.
```

---

Then to add the data to your dataframe ([source](https://gist.github.com/sammatuba/70269c2b5268a83344f5de609ea9b3cc)):

```py
df[['long.', 'lat.']] = pd.DataFrame(df['wkt'].apply(get_long_lat).tolist())
```